# UIView animation layoutIfneeded not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I am using this message to animate a customer view to the lower edge of the device screen. I've connected the layout constraint and set initial constant as -60. When the value is set to 0, I expect the view to animate to top. But unfortunately the expected functionality is not working. Even the method is called, the view is hoped up when interface orientation changes. I am using Xcode 6.4 and iOS 8 as base sdks. Any help will be appreciated.

```
if (alertVisible)
{
     self.alertViewVerticalConstraint.constant = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations: ^{
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.alertView];
        self.alertView.alpha = 0.5;

        [self.alertView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
else
{
     self.alertViewVerticalConstraint.constant = -60;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations: ^{
        self.alertView.alpha = 0.0;

        [self.alertView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to animate the constraint changes, you have to defines the line within the animation block.

So your code will become something like this,

```
if (alertVisible)
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations: ^{
    self.alertViewVerticalConstraint.constant = 0;

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.alertView];
    self.alertView.alpha = 0.5;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
 }];
}
else
{
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations: ^{
       self.alertViewVerticalConstraint.constant = -60;

       self.alertView.alpha = 0.0;

      [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
}
```

Comment: Done the edit! still the functionality is not working!

Comment: I have updated the answer. Replace [self.alertView layoutIfNeeded]; with [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: FYI, normally you'd update your constraints OUTSIDE the block. This is how apple showed it, and how I've always done it. Then, within the block, call `[view layoutIfNeeded]`, as Varun said. it shouldn't be on your `alertView`

Comment: If it still doesn't work after updating your constraint constant outside the block, and calling `layoutIfNeeded` on the alertView's superview, then try a different constant value and see if you can get it to appear on screen. Maybe the constant needs to be something else.

Comment: `Whenever you want to animate the constraint changes, you have to define the line within the animation block.` This is completely false. Do not do this.