# Xcode 8 return height= 1000 and Width =1000 for UIview (actual size is (328,40))

Tags: uiview, height, width

Since i installed Xcode 8, i am in trouble.
I didnt get the correct value for each or any UIView.

I also got the constraint alert for UIView. So i update it.
But view returns 1000 as width or height.
I tried or search a lot. But didnt got any proper solution.
pls help me.

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475456/ios10-viewdidload-frame-width-height-not-initialized-correctly), you should call `layoutIfNeeded` for your view in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    // Now all your subviews are sized as you expect
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. i will try this.

Comment: It works for me for swift - self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: doesn't work for a textView inputAccessoryView. But I guess I can set the frame manually before setting the inputAccessoryView... But I hate hard code :(

Answer (score 1):

For *Swift 3* :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in xcode 8, I couldn't get layoutIfNeeded fully working, so I had to save the storyboard as an Xcode 7 file.  however, this issue seems to be fixed in xcode8.1
  [see this comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40099892/922681)