# The size of UIView/UIImageView on xib(Xcode8) become (1000, 1000)

Tags: ios, xib, xcode8

I use autolayout on xib to create my UI.

When I finish my UI. It work well on simulator.

But when I open Xcode8 next time, the xib show strange.
Some UIView and UIImageView become big.
The size become (1000, 1000)

[image: Wrong Size]

Even so, when I run on simulator, it look well.
But the xib cannot be modify easily.

I try to update the frame. It become worse

[image: Worse after updating the frames]

How should I deal with it?

Comment: What does your original xib UI look like? Could you provide an image?

Comment: I'm limited to show image directly. You can see the image by the link. And I have found it is Xcode8' issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Xcode8's issues. And that is fixed in Xcode8.1 beta2.

> Xcode 8.0 did not always restore view frames from storyboards and xibs when layouts were
>   ambiguous. Xcode 8.1 fixes several of these issues. If you have encountered these issues, resolve the
>   ambiguity in the Auto Layout issues and update frames. Xcode 8.1 will persist them correctly.
>   (28221021, 28244619)

Details can be found in [release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Documentation/Xcode_8.1_beta_3_SDK_Release_Notes/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_8.1_beta_3.pdf)