# Make view circular without masksToBounds

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, cornerradius

as seen in radar (28342777) - there is an issue in iOS10 when creating `UIImageView`. Since the views are made automatically to (1000x1000px) sometimes they won't display.

turning off `masksToBounds` will make them appear correctly, but don't allow to make the circular.
I tried using `cornerRadius` by itself, but it won't work.

Is there a work around?

Comment: Can you not init the view with a smaller frame on instantiation?

Comment: I have done that in IB. I have constraints on it saying width = height = 64. But it doesn't change

Comment: could you try subclassing it, having your own custom init that calls init and sets the frame subsequently, that way it's done for you before the image is set?

Comment: @Woodstock not sure how to do this. I am using custom TableViewCells with UIImageView. Do I need to code this in my customCell class ?

Comment: actually I think there is an even easier solution shown here, check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475456/ios10-viewdidload-frame-width-height-not-initialized-correctly

Comment: @Woodstock okay got a solution with your help now. In my cell class i put just above masksToBounds = true - self.layoutIfNeeded(). I also needed to call self.userInteractionEnabled = true

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make your UIImageView circular, you have to do this in viewDidLayoutSubviews instead of viewDidLoad method, as:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        self.yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.yourImageView.frame.size.height/2
        self.yourImageView.clipsToBounds = true

    }
```